# how to remove if end date is expired in python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My gql model is

```
start_date = db.DateTimeProperty()
end_date = db.DateTimeProperty()
```

my class is

```
class GetHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        promos = Promotion.all()

        self.render_response("/admin/promotion/index.html", promos=promos)
```

if `end_date` is expired [`end_date<datetime.now`] it should remove from my admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1843331/tim-castelijns) 's answer:

```
now = datetime.now()  # get current datetime
q = db.Query(Promotion)
q = q.filter('end_date <', now)
for promo in q.run():  # loop over filtered promos
    promo.delete()  # delete instance from datastore
```

The documentation discourages the use of [fetch instead of run](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass?hl=en#Query_fetch). And it's probably a bad idea to fetch all the promos.

Comment: @uday my pleasure, but I'm not sure if you use my answer or Tim's. You should be careful because it could be a problem if you have a lot of Promotions.

Comment: I only know fetch() since I work with ndb instead of db, that's why I used that. But your way with the filtering is better anyway

Answer (score 0):

Compare the dates and act accordingly

```
promos = Promotion.all().fetch()  # fetch all promos
now = datetime.now()  # get current datetime
for promo in promos:  # loop over all promos
    if promo.end_date > now:  # compare promo date to 'now'
        promo.delete()  # delete instance from datastore
```

comparing date(time)s is as simple as using `>` or `<`